# Xcode 5 continuous integration: The Xcode Service is not enabled on the server

Tags: xcode, service, integration, continuous

I've just installed Xcode 5 and OS X Server and trying to set up continuous integration. I followed [these](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/200-Adopting_a_Continuous_Integration_Workflow/adopt_continuous_integration.html) steps but when I try to add server in Xcode I get the following error:

"The Xcode Service is not enabled on the server '...'. Contact the administrator for assistance."

The Xcode service appears to be up and running, it shows as "Available" in the Server app and is accessible through HTTP.

Is there any way this can be troubleshooted?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It looks like there are network name resolving issues there. Try using server's IP address instead of its name. It worked for me.

Comment: Using IP address, it does allow to connect to Server, but then whenever I add Remote repository or Push, Xcode crashes

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Server.app is strange and it does not directly report issues with embedded webserver. Therefore, if you are running some other Webserver (or something else on 80 / 443), whole Xcode CI will not start properly and Xcode will report this issue.

For me, shutting down Apache and restarting the Xcode Server part solved the issue, yet as I need Apache running on my computer, I'm not going to use CI in it's current state. :-(

Possibly, I have to find out how to change default port for Xcode CI.